# Computing roots of a very high degree polynomial

Tags: polynomial-math, numerical-computing

Here is my problem ; for my research, I believe that the complex numbers I am looking at are precisely the (very large) set of roots of some high degree polynomial, of degree $\sim 2^n$ (~ 2^n) where $1 \le n \le 10 \sim 15$ (1 <= n <= 10 ~ 15). Mathematica has been running for the whole day on my computer, and I wondered if any other program out there would be faster than Mathematica so that I could compute more of those roots. If I had more examples it would REALLY help. The thing I need the program to be able to do is simple : I give you a polynomial of very high degree, and I want to numerically plot its complex roots. I don't care about multiplicity.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How come my TeX is not displayed in mathematical symbols? It doesn't work like on Math Stack Exchange here? I thought that TeXing was all over Stack Overflow.